# Detailed personal information on resume

Tags: resume

Should I put my nationality, date of birth and compulsory millitary service on my resume? I've seen many templates don't even mention anything from the above and I'm not sure if I can benefit from that.

Comment: Are those things relevant to the job you are applying for? (Is it an international mustering out for the over 50's company?)

Comment: Can you describe your location and industry you work in? That may have an impact on the answers.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer may not be suitable for Germany)

This is quite a general answer. There will be exceptions for some industries.

**Nationality**

No, you do not need to include your nationality. But if you need to obtain a visa to work in the country (and will need employer assistance), you should make that clear.

**Date of Birth**

No, you do not need to include your date of birth.

**Compulsory Millitary Service**

If you think that will influence their decision to hire you or not, you should consider  adding it.